# Incorrect flag limit?

Tags: bug, flags, moderation

Only 10 flags are allowed to be used a day for a user with my reputation. When I use 10 flags and then try to use an eleventh, it tells me that I am only allowed *11* flags a day. [image: incorrect flag count]

However, I am only allowed 10 flags per day. Is this a bug or is it somehow on my end?

Comment: Are you sure your limit is not 11? Because once you have cast 10 helpful flags, your limit increases to 11.

Comment: sigh..... I feel like this is REALLY a missed opportunity for a Spinal Tap joke :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at your profile shows you have cast 14 helpful flags.

The maximum number of flags you can cast increases by one for every 10 helpful flags you cast. Currently, that number is 11, thus the message is correct.